# Mounting via cifs or sshfs at boot depending on wifi SSID

Tags: boot, mount, fstab, cifs, sshfs

I have a ubuntu home server 12.10 that is available over the internet for SSH connections.  I also have my ubuntu laptop that I use at home and when on the road.  What I would like is that during the boot, depending on the available WiFi connection, it either chooses cifs when on my home network, or SSHFS otherwise.

I don't want to use SSHFS by default on my home network as by going via dyndns and my limited home internet connection upload speed, I think it will be significantly slower for day to day tasks at home.

I don't think fstab has some sort of heirarchical mount tree that would allow me to do this (from what I have read in the man pages anyway).

Does this seem logical/reasonable, or am I going about it the wrong way? And if it is valid, how would I go about doing it?

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

David

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a user-land script that runs when you log in? Try to do the cifs mount in /etc/fstab, if it fails do the sshfs when you log in.

Just add this to your login scripts:

```
mount | grep -q 'myhomeserver' || sshfs mydyndns /mountpoint
```